# python input defined in files recomendations

Tags: python, python-2.7

I need your helps for  best practices for input defined.

Below is the input file i used read for my python execution.

Input file:

```
 Location number_of_trucks type_of_goods number_of_stores
 US         10               20             5
 AUS        4                15             4
 UK         20               30             50
```

Is that correct way of defining input?

python script prompt location id location.

I have written code something if some one add the location in input file  program automatically detects ask for selection location.

Below is the code:

```
with open('input.txt') as f:
    countlines = len(f.readlines())
total = 1
for x in range(1,countlines):
    with open('inputfile.txt') as f:
        location = f.readlines()[x]
        location = location.split()
        location = location[0]
        print"{}. {}".format(total, location)
        total = total + 1

location = raw_input("Choose Location:")
```

To handle input file. i written another file to remove empty lines.

I need your help. Is i am doing right way or is there any other easiest and recommended way to achieve the same

Comment: Why do you open you file inside the for loop? You open it multiple times that way. It might be better to read your file line by line

Comment: so only that is the problem remaining method is right, Thanks a lof pointing out

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are actually trying to do with your program. Currently it looks like you are trying to print something like this:

```
1. US
2. AUS
3. UK
```

If that is what you want you can do the same thing with:

```
m = 0
for line in open("input.txt"):
   print str(m)+". "+line.split()[0] 
   m+=1
```

However, at the end you ask for their location. Is that something you want used in your program, or is it for something else? Also, I assumed input.txt and inputfile.txt were the same thing. If they aren't, what is what you showed and what is the other file?